# Extract an "average polygon" from multiple right-turn loop polygons?

Tags: openstreetmap

Now we are using OSM and OSMnx python package to do a job of extracting the right turn loop in a designated area. We have extracted all the right-turn loops features in the area(Such as the number of nodes, angle, edge length).

We want to extract a polygon shape that represents the characteristics of the whole right turn loops in this area. But these right-turn loops have different polygonal shapes, such as triangles, quadrilaterals, etc., it is not possible to directly handle all right-turn loops.

**One idea is to classify these right-turning loop polygons according to the number of nodes before processing.** But I encountered the following problems:

1. At first I want to directly average the included angle and edge length of polygons with the same number of nodes to get the final polygon. But there are many curved roads in the actual roads, which makes the included angle meaningless.
2. How to get a representative right-turn loop polygon from these right-turn loops using these features(nodes number, included angle, edge length)?
3. Maybe we can’t solve the problem by using these features. Is there any other better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of what you have so far and where it needs to go from there, to clarify what you are asking?